# The players hacking in Counter-Strike: Global Offensive?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, counter-strike

I started playing CS:GO several days ago, and it's obvious from watching players that they were using wall hacks. It hasn't been fun playing this multiplayer game as a beginner versus experienced hackers.

Before I decide whether it's worthwhile to continue playing this game, can anyone give a gross approximation of how many players are using hacks?

Comment: To know how many, you must count them. If you can count them you know them. If you know them you can ban them. I don't think it will be possible to know how many hackers/cheaters/script-kiddys are playing. I don't really know how many players are doing illegal software do boost there performance but i don't encounter them. Only person who "pre-aim" to have a better position to shoot.

Comment: No offense, but if you're new to the game you might think people are wallhacking when they actually listen to footsteps. The experienced players have their sounds like footsteps turned up so they know exactly where everyone is.

Comment: everyone better than me is a hacker! and everyone worse is a noob! such is the rule of online-gaming!

Comment: @Izzo don't forget about voice communication. I used to think that people finding me in certain spots were wall hackers, but now I know better; they have voice comm and are alerting teammates to my location.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm not the only one saying this, but i assure, there is a huge difference between a hacker and a good player. 
For instance, a good player can:

- Hear footsteps, so he knows where you are coming from even without seeing you
- Knows key positions: He knows where you probably are standing to defend
- Important passages on the maps: He knows that if you shoot at this wall he can hit someone who is defending at a key position!

There are almost no hackers on CS:GO, just deal with the fact that they are on a different skill level then you are used to.

Comment: "There are almost no hackers on CS:GO". I don't even believe that statement for one minute. Just go to any CS:GO community, and you'll see a lot of vented frustration about cheaters at any skill level, whether it be Silver or Global Elite

Comment: Honestly, i'm just speaking on a personal level.
A lot of people just complain blindly about it. Even if, the question is basically saying that he is getting A LOT of them, even if he just started playing. I have a lot of hours ( note: only in ranked, no idea about casual ) and i've never felt like this game as too much hacking issues. Again, this is based on personal experience, so you might have a different story to tell

Comment: In my experience mid-tier ranks such as double AKs and Aks see very little hackers. Once I started to stop playing and getting deranked due to inactivity I started to see more hackers (I confirmed this because players on the teams I played against later got VAC banned) in the lower leagues, like silver and nova

Comment: Sad actually. As it gone worse in rec  ent weeks/months? I played a lot in silver, but about 6 months ago

Comment: It's not so bad but the main issue in Silvers is not hackers, but smurfers, but the issue in GE and LE is hackers.

Answer (score 1):

As a beginner you will face many smurfs (skilled players, new accounts). I'm pretty sure that hackers exist. But as a beginner, there are many, but many smurfs.
You should try to play casual before you go comp.